# Using meta to redirect in php, but file is in another folder

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, echo, meta

I have a little issue here I have been looking all over and haven't found a solution.

I want to redirect my page once my users have logged in, but I will log them into a secure server. I'm using virtual host on apache so one is the http page and the othe one is the https server for secure encrypted connection.

on my login.php I have this

```
if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
    echo "Welcome, now you can continue to our secure webpage. You will be automatically redirected in 5 seconds.....";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=5;url=index.php>";
} else {
    echo "Incorrect Username/Password, please try again.....";
    echo "You will be automatically redirected in 5 seconds.....";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=5;url=login.php?id=1>";
}}
```

but actually what I want is that instead of making the redirection to the index.php file on /var/www/http, I want to make the redirection to index.php on the directory /var/www/https/

That is my problem I have tried a lot of stuff but nothing that line will be like

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=5;url=index.php>";
```

There is one more problem I'm using a VPN to connect to the server, so I cannot connect like  `echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=5;url=https://www.url.com>";`
I cannot go to the DNS and resolve the name and then get the IP, and like it is a VPN the address is internal I cannot put any external address because the problem will persist, that is my real problem is there any way to do it internally??

Thank you very much for your help

Thanks in advance.

CD

Comment: Don't Use words like "Thanks in advance" or "Thank you very much for your help" and don't use signature "CD". You can write "Any help would be appreciable." Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP header:

```
header("location: <url>");
```

like so:

```
header("location: https://<etc>"); // redirect to different page but only if no other output has been generated
exit; // prevents further execution of code
```

Be aware that you cannot redirect to a filepath, but only to an url. So if you want to serve the HTTPS page your webserver must serve it via a domain/url. So you would need to use a SSL certificate and configure your webserver to serve the https (port 443) request from within your https directory.

I hope this make sense ;)

If you want to continue using the html redirect (perhaps if you are using the redirect in your html or if you can't use the php redirect):

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=5;url=https://<domain>/login.php?id=1>";
```

Seeing your comment on the other answer concerning your VPS. You still need to configure your server to handle the request to the 443 (ssl) port. Even if your server has a dynamic IP or you're connecting through VPN, you can always edit your vhosts file to point a certain (non-existing) domain to an IP, even if it is a local, network or VPN tunneled IP. Your main focus at this time would be to configure your server correctly.

Comment: Thx that how i use it and it works perfect but now im connecting via VPN so I cannot resolve the name, I'm thinking if it I have to install a DNS server as well but is to messy. I just want to find a way to redirect somehow to a filepath.  I used a symbolik link but that just opens the file does not make a new connection and request the SSL certificate and so on....

Thx in advance

Comment: As said. You will only be able to use SSL if your webserver is configured to serve https pages on that specific port. You are now on port 80 (default http port) and want to switch to port 443 (SSL) by redirecting to a different page on port 80 --- you see where your thought is in conflict? You will need to enable https and request the correct port/url to redirect to SSL succesfully.

Comment: exactly I understand the issue so no way of doing it, i have to find someway for the vpn to indicate the users that the https server is on the private ip address as well. that can be quite an issue

Answer (score 0):

Give it complete url of your https index file:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=5;url=https://YourHTTPSURL.com/index.php>";
```

**EDIT:**

As discussed in comments you can use a URL like this:

```
https://192.168.1.1:443/index.php
```

Comment: Thx Hanky Panky

There is one problem with that im using a VPN to connect to the server, so I cannot connect like that I cannot go to the DNS and resolve the name and then get the IP, and like it is a VPN the address are internal I cannot put there external address because the problem will persist, that is my real problem is there any way to do it internally????

thanks in advance

Comment: @user2130687  Maybe there is a design flaw here, you cannot put a VPN url to be accessible on HTTP for everyone who is not even connected to your VPN. It has to be accessible from outside. However to answer your question you can just put the URL with IP rather than domain name if DNS cant be set like you mentioned. `https://192.168.1.1:443/index.php`

Comment: Thx @hankypanky actually that will solve the problem and will only allow people inside my vpn to access the secure server and the http page will be accessible from the outside. This is a work in progress and a little project that is why maybe has a flaw or intend to have some academical purpose